# How to pass JS variable into Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my Laravel blade template I have a javascript snippet that produces a variable that holds an index (named nextIndex), for an array. I would like to use that index in a Vue instance, like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        url: "{{route('showphoto')}}/{{$photos[nextIndex]->id}}"
    }
});
```

I have spent hours searching the internet and reading the documentation, but maybe I am looking at the wrong places. How can I pass the JS variable *nextIndex* into the vue data above?

EDITED
I also tried it this way (with the @ before nextIndex and creating the whole url outside of the Vue instance:

```
var key = {{ $photo->id}};
var photos = {!!$photos!!};
var @nextIndex = 0;
for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
    if(photos[i]['id'] === key && !(i >= photos.length-1)){
        @nextIndex = i+1; // if not the last index, give me the next index
        break;
    } else if(photos[i]['id'] === key && (i == photos.length-1)) {
        @nextIndex = 0; //if this is the last index, give me the first one
        break;
    }
 }

 var url = "{{ route('showphoto') }}/{{ $photos[@nextIndex]->id }}";

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        url: url
    }
});
```

This gives me the exact same error message though:

```
Undefined index: nextIndex
```

Comment: You say you want to pass `nextIndex`, but in the code you're passing `$photos[nextIndex]->id`. What do you see when you look at the HTML source code?

Comment: edwin: I get an error message saying "Undefined index: nextIndex". As you can tell I am a newbie and what I want to figure out is how to use nextIndex as a variable instead of a fixed number as the index.